# date variable manipulation

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, date, db2-luw, db2-11.5

I'm working on DB2 stored procedure, which will be called by the Korn Shell (.ksh). My DB2 version is 11.5 and it is running on AIX.

I was stuck in TIMESTAMP to DATE conversion. Below is my requirement.

```
If s_day < day(s_date) then
start_date = YYYY-MM from s_date + 1 day from s_day 
end if
```

Note here `s_date` is DATE variable, `s_day` is CHAR variable and `start_date` is DATE variable.

So I tried, the following code, but got an error.

```
   IF s_day < DAY(s_date) 
    THEN
    SET start_date = DATE (DATE(s_date,'YYYY-MM') || s_day + 1);
    END IF
```

Sample values

```
s_day =03
s_date= 15/05/2020
expected output start_date is 2020-05-04
```

Can anyone help me to achieve expected output?

Comment: You should indicate your Db2 version and platform

Comment: DB2 version is 11.5 version and it is AIX

Comment: Please add as much information as possible by hitting the [edit] button. Things like the actual error message you are receiving. Please don't add as a comment as they sometimes get deleted. Welcome to DBA.SE.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
IF int(s_day) < DAY(s_date) 
THEN
    SET start_date = THIS_MONTH(s_date) + int(s_day) days;
END IF
```

Comment: This may not work in all Db2 versions though

Comment: True but the Db2 version and OS is not specified - it is Db2 11.1

Comment: DB2 version is 11.5 version and it is AIX

Comment: So it should work - have you tried it ?